# how to identify scanner,webcam etc in system using java

Tags: java, webcam, image-scanner

I trying to acquire images from scanner, webcam, etc. devices connected with my system or network using Java. In Java, we have third party libraries JTWAIN for scanner and JMF/FMJ for webcam. Before acquiring images I need shown popup, connected devices like scanner and webcam then I will select the device then acquiring the images.

My questions are:

1. Detecting devices scanner, webcam, etc.
2. Is there any open source library supporting both scanner and webcam devices?